# Why I don't see different/unique outputs of my variable value after each atomicAdd?

Tags: cuda, atomic

I'm new to CUDA.
I was trying to implement a trie data structure on GPU but it didn't work. I noticed my atomicAdd isn't working as I expected.
So I did some experiment with atomicAdd. I wrote this piece of code :

```
#include <cstdio>

//__device__ int *a; //I also tried the code with using this __device__
                     //variable and allocating it inside kernel instead
                     //using cudaMalloc. Same Result

__global__ void AtomicTestKernel (int*a)
{
    *a = 0;
    __syncthreads();
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        if (threadIdx.x % 2)
        {
            atomicAdd(a, 1);
            printf("threadsIndex = %d\t&\ta : %d\n",threadIdx.x,*a);
        }
        else
        {
            atomicAdd(a, 1);
            printf("threadsIndex = %d\t&\ta : %d\n", threadIdx.x, *a);
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int * d_a;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_a, sizeof(int));

    AtomicTestKernel << <1, 10 >> > (d_a);

    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    return 0;
}
```

correct me where I'm wrong about this code :

1 - according to CUDA's Programming guide : (on atomic Functions)

> ... In other words, no other thread can access this address until the
>   operation is complete

2 - the `int * d_a` resides in global memory and so is the kernel's input : `int * a`
because its allocated using `cudaMalloc` (according to this 3 minute video : [Udacity CUDA - Global Memory](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=19qJjMFKG3g&index=93&list=PLGvfHSgImk4aweyWlhBXNF6XISY3um82_)) and therefore all of threads are seeing the same `int * a` and not each of them has it's own

3 - In the code as before every `printf` there is an `atomicAdd` so I expect each of those `printf`s has the value of `*a` different from previous and therefore unique.

BUT in the result I get I see so many same variable of `*a`
 this is the result I get :

```
threadsIndex = 0        &       a : 5
threadsIndex = 2        &       a : 5
threadsIndex = 4        &       a : 5
threadsIndex = 6        &       a : 5
threadsIndex = 8        &       a : 5
threadsIndex = 1        &       a : 10
threadsIndex = 3        &       a : 10
threadsIndex = 5        &       a : 10
threadsIndex = 7        &       a : 10
threadsIndex = 9        &       a : 10
threadsIndex = 0        &       a : 15
threadsIndex = 2        &       a : 15
threadsIndex = 4        &       a : 15
threadsIndex = 6        &       a : 15
threadsIndex = 8        &       a : 15
threadsIndex = 1        &       a : 20
threadsIndex = 3        &       a : 20
threadsIndex = 5        &       a : 20
threadsIndex = 7        &       a : 20
threadsIndex = 9        &       a : 20
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since all instruction are executed in the same time within a warp your code is executing all atomic instruction THEN performing the printf, as a consequence, you are reading the result of all your atomic operations.

Here is the exexution of instruction within a warp :

```
Instruction | threadId 1       | threadId 2       | *a        
____________________________________________________________
AtomicAdd   | increasing value | waiting          | 1  
              waiting          | increasing value | 2
---------------------------------------------- Warp finished instruction of all AtomicAdd
reading *a  | read value       | read value       | 2
```

to read the previous value of an atomic operation check the result of the method atomicAdd

```
int previousValue = atomicAdd(a, 1);
```

you can have some informations here : https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#atomicadd

Comment: Thanks ! Yeah I tried that and I saw the unique values.